# iframe in Smarty (tpl)

Tags: html, iframe, powerbi, smarty, react-fullstack

I have this iframe html code

```
<iframe title="Sales-AdventureWork - Page 5" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOWFjOWZjYjAtY2RmYi00OGYxLTg2ZWYtNjQ5NjJkN2E5ODAzIiwidCI6ImUwYjNmMTA2LWU2Y2QtNDNjOS05NGUxLTRkMzMwMWNjZWMzOCIsImMiOjl9" frameborder="0"  scrolling="no" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

from power bi which working very well in html page but when I try to embed it into smarty tpl file  it shows it partial view like pic num 1
[image]

but the same code working very well in html like pic num 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Height cannot be 100%. Should be a static number.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).